# Error: workbox-sw is needed by the service while running production mode

Tags: angular, jhipster

Following error appears when I try to run following command:

```
yarn run webpack:prod:main
```

Tail of the build log:

```
...
18081ms additional asset processing
0ms chunk asset optimization
 94% asset optimizationMergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation started...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation completed...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
605ms asset optimization
95% emittingMergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...
Error: workbox-sw is needed by the service worker and could not be copied     
over to your new site. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod ' 
\target\www\workbox-sw.prod.v2.1.2.js'
at Error (native)
at Promise.all.then.catch ( \node_modules\workbox-
build\build\lib\utils\copy-workbox-sw.js:17:13)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Following command works but the /app/vendor.bundle.js is too large (~ 12Mb)

```
yarn run webpack:build
```

**SOLUTION:** (fixed in upcoming jHipster version)

http://www.jhipster.tech/2017/12/27/jhipster-release-4.13.1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a jHispter's bug from v 4.13. It is fixed in 4.13.1

http://www.jhipster.tech/2017/12/27/jhipster-release-4.13.1.html